# ERROR: missing "LOOP" at end of SQL expression

Tags: postgresql, while-loop

I'm getting the above error in my code, which indicates the 'while' line.
I'm trying to find the number of intersection points to a line on some gis data.
I've copied the code verbatim, the postgis code shouldn't affect the problem.
(And if I'm trying to do this in a really stupid way, please say. I'm only a beginner)

```
create or replace function border() returns table(x real, sum bigint) as $$
declare x real;
begin   
    x := -35.5724;
    while x > -36.4 do
        return query select x,sum(st_npoints(st_intersection(the_geom,st_setsrid(st_makeline(st_point(173.3,x),st_point(175,x)),4167)))) from auckland_numberlines;
        x := x - 0.1;
    end while
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while x > -36.4 do
    return query select x,sum(st_npoints(st_intersection(the_geom,st_setsrid(st_makeline(st_point(173.3,x),st_point(175,x)),4167)))) from auckland_numberlines;
        x := x - 0.1;    
    end while
```

should be

```
WHILE x > -36.4 LOOP
    return query select x,sum(st_npoints(st_intersection(the_geom,st_setsrid(st_makeline(st_point(173.3,x),st_point(175,x)),4167)))) from auckland_numberlines;
        x := x - 0.1;
END LOOP ;
```